# How can I only start to write to a character array if I find a certain string and stop once I find another string?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have data coming in from a site:

```
    try {
        String webPage = 
        URL url = new URL("www.google.com");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String result = sb.toString();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Now I really want to know how I can only store data that is coming from google in the charArray after for example [div] so I get "hi"  and stop once I see [/div]

Sorry if there are 1 million other posts similar to this I'm not very good with java so I dont know if just looking something up less specific would work for this fine.

Comment: You can try putting charArray in string and use the method startsWith.

Comment: So, you want to parse HTML and extract information from the HTML document, right? Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank you very much! Im glad people will help so fast.

Comment: @JBNizet Jsoup had the same problem I need to start once its already close to the <span> because the html is 46000 characters so it stopps searching after 1000 or so